# Are the mean and variance of a dihedral angle periodic?

Tags: trigonometry, angle, periodic-functions, dihedral-groups

In biomolecular science, a dihedral angle is periodic with a period of $2\pi$. It ranges from -180 to 180 degrees. Now, if for 5 dihedral angles, I want to calculate their mean and variance. Will the mean and variance also be periodic? If so, what would be the periods? Also, what would be the correct way to calculate the mean and standard deviation that take the periodicity into account?

The answer I have in my mind is that the mean will be periodic with a period of $2\pi$ as well but the variance is not periodic because it can not be seen as a vector, but I'm not absolutely sure ...

As for the calculation of the mean, I think the best way is probably to use the [two-argument arctangent function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2). For example, if we have $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, instead of calculating the mean as $\frac{1}{2}(\theta_1 + \theta_2)$, it should be
$$\operatorname{atan}\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin(\theta_1) + \sin(\theta_2)\right), \frac{1}{2}\left(\cos(\theta_1) + \cos(\theta_2)\right)\right)$$

Namely, the two arguments of the function atan is the average of the sine and cosine functions. However, I'm not so sure about the correct way to calculate the variance. I don't think it is as simple as using the atan function, with the two arguments being the variance of sine and cosine functions because that would lead to a variance of 90 between -180 and +180, while it should have been 0.

Comment: It does not make sense to compute either the mean or variance of a random angle at all. To calculate the mean you have to average a collection of angles, which means adding up $n$ angles (this is fine), then dividing by $n$ (this is not fine; it does not produce a unique result). The variance is even worse because you have to square and it is not meaningful to square angles.

Comment: What does make sense, given a random angle $\theta$, is computing the mean and variance of $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan sorry, but I disagree with your thought. While calculating the mean and variance of the sine and cosine functions also makes sense, I'm absolutely sure that the mean of the angle itself still makes sense. That's how we did in a published work where an averaged angle is used as an order parameter to be biased in a biomolecular simulation. If you try the equation that I showed above, you'll now at least using atan2 to calculate an averaged angle does make sense. I'm not so sure about the variance, but squared angles are not meaningless.

Comment: The square root of the variance, i.e. standard deviation, measures how spread out the dihedrals are and the unit should be degree/radian and it does make sense, so is the variance.